How to Place a Smooth "Breathing" Above the E with Textgreek?
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\textgreek{>i >E}
\end{document}

which gives

I don't understand why the "curly comma" is not placed atop the E as it was for the iota? Can someone show me how to do this with textgreek?
UPDATE EDIT
e.g.,


You'll find no text in ancient Greek that puts diacritics (accents or breathings) over capital letters: they're always set before the capital letter.
Diacritics entered ancient Greek in the Hellenistic period and have been written this way for about 22 centuries. I see no reason to go against this tradition.
This is the relevant part of the Greek Extended Unicode block:

I found a modern citation of the same book:

Here's a possibly clearer version of your picture.

You can note that

the breathing is placed correctly in front of the Α;
the breathing is missing in front of the Ο;
the accent over the η is incorrect: it should be ή instead of ὴ;
the word “Ἐκκλησίας” is misspelled.

All signs that the source is unreliable.
(Thanks to yannisl for support.)

Please see my update edit.

@Jethro Bad typesetting. Can you please share the source?

Is what I have displayed then in the MWE output correct?

Source: p. 2 of https://dn720302.ca.archive.org/0/items/churchofchristap00berr/churchofchristap00berr.pdf

@Jethro Trust me: the breathing over the capital epsilon is wrong.

I believe you; I just want to make sure I typeset it correctly. If I am interpreting your previous comments correctly, it would seem that what is already displayed in the output of the MWE is correct. I was just hoping you would have confirmed that. I'll assume that it is based on what you've said previously. Thank you for your helpful answer.

I just saw your updated answer. Many thanks. The system (previously) brought me directly to the comments.

@Jethro  egreg is 100% correct on this one. The image you posted is badly printed and the word is mispelt also.

@yannisl I was quite certain egreg was correct. And thanks for pointing out the misspelling.  I guess I'll have to consult DeepL for the correct spelling or look up my good friend Spiros from graduate school who now lives in Athens :-)   Actually, I've been thinking about contacting him anyway.  Thank you for your comment.

@yannisl Thanks for chiming in. Not only there's an epsilon instead of eta: there are at least three errors, besides the misplacement of the breathing.

@egreg: Excellent and learned answer, as always – I'm not sure about No. 3 though. IIRC from school, I'd say the grave accent over the eta is correct, or at least justified, according to the rule of oxytones: "whenever an oxytone word is followed by a non-enclitic word, the acute is changed to a grave" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_accent#Oxytone_words

@marquinho I trusted the modern citation. Maybe we can find a more authoritative one.
